# Jquery trigger() is not working on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried a lot of variations of this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#slide_click').trigger('click');
        });
    </script>
```

This should triggers a button with an onclick event when the document is ready

```
<button id="slide_click" onclick="gotoSlide(<?php echo $_GET["goto"] ?>)">Trigger</button>
```

The gotoSlide function needs an integer parameter, what it does is it should go to the specific slide on my gallery slider. But apparently it doesn't work. I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm using a jquery plugin for the slider called Advanced Slider. Am I using the trigger() function correctly?

Comment: why don't you invoke `gotoSlide` directly in `document ready`?

Comment: It looks like what you have should work. Put an alert or something inside `gotoSlide` and see if it actually gets called: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/qFpFG/

Comment: Your trigger code looks fine.  What do you mean exactly by "doesn't work"?  Do you get a JS error?  Could you post a link to a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: The gotoSlide() function has this piece of code: `function gotoSlide(index){ slider.gotoSlide(index); }` I even put an alert in the gotoSlide() function just to see if it fires when the document is redy and it does. But it doesn't execute this: `slider.gotoSlide(index);`

Comment: @ExpExc I tried that also and I didn't get the desired effect. Thanks. :)

Comment: @ChesterSabado if it's the case, you should check your `gotoSlide` method of `slider` object. You should also update or close your question, because the problem is not `jQuery trigger`

Answer (score 3):

Missing single quotes `onclick="gotoSlide('<?php echo $_GET["goto"] ?>')"`

Answer (score 0):

The code seemed to work for me. I tried alerting in click event

```
<button id="slide_click" onclick="alert('Hi');">Button #1</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nyta7/

What do you have in the gotoSlide() method?

Comment: This: function gotoSlide(index){
    slider.gotoSlide(index);
   }

Comment: Yes my code seems to work fine. I even put an alert in the gotoSlide() function just to see if it fires when the document is redy and it does. But it doesn't execute this: `slider.gotoSlide(index);`